# アプリを消してもチェックボックスのチェックが消えないようにするには？

Tags: android

動画を紹介するアプリを作成しています。

ユーザーが気に入った動画をチェックボックスでチェックし、アプリを閉じてもチェック状態は保たれるようにしたいです。

XMLファイルによってチェックボックスを表示させることはできますが、上記の機能を盛り込むにはどうすればよいのでしょうか。

開発環境はAndroid Studio 、言語はJavaです。

Answer (score 2):

方法としてはいくつかありますが、DBを使うのが一番良いでしょう。

例えば、お気に入りテーブルを作成して管理をするようにします。

チェックボックスをチェックされたらお気に入りテーブルにインサート。
チェックボックスからチェックを外された場合はお気に入りテーブルから削除します。
アプリを再起動した場合はお気に入りテーブルに登録されている動画のチェックボックスを初期表示でチェックするようにします。

DBのライブラリはいくつかあるので、[ここ](https://www.gaprot.jp/pickup/tips/android-db-choice)を参考に使いやすいものを選んでみてください。
私個人としてはRealmがオススメです。